# Does a local ring with a separably closed residue field admit a universal homeomorphism from a local ring with algebraically closed residue field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a local ring with separably closed residue field. Under what conditions does there exist a local ring $B$ with an algebraically closed residue field and a local homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ inducing a universal homeomorphism on spectra?

Comment: Is there a typo in the title? "homeomorphism" is not at the level of the ring.

Comment: @YCor You're right, though I'm not sure how else to write the title without surpassing the character limit.

Comment: You don't have to write the whole question in the title. Would "*Embedding into a local ring with algebraically closed residue field*" make a good title?

Comment: An example where this is not possible: if $A$ is normal of mixed characteristic and $\kappa_A = A/\mathfrak m_A$ is not algebraically closed. Indeed, such a map $A \to B$ is integral by Tag [04DF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DF) and radicial by Tag [01S4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S4), so $\operatorname{Frac}(A) \to \operatorname{Frac}(B)$ is purely inseparable. Since $\operatorname{char}(A) = 0$ this means $\operatorname{Frac}(A) = \operatorname{Frac}(B)$, which by normality implies $A = B$.

Comment: An example where this is possible: if $A$ has equicharacteristic (i.e. contains a field). For equicharacteristic $0$ there is nothing to prove, and for equicharacteristic $p > 0$ you can take the perfection $B = \operatorname{colim} F^n_* A$, Indeed, $A \to B$ is a universal homeomorphism since Frobenius is, so $B$ is local and $A \to B$ is local, and Frobenius is surjective on $B/\mathfrak m_B$ since it is so on $B$.

Answer (score 4):

You can always do this when $A$ has equicharacteristic (i.e. contains a field). For equicharacteristic $0$, there is nothing to prove, and for equicharacteristic $p > 0$ you can take the perfection¹
$$B = \underset{n}{\operatorname{colim}} F^n_* A.$$
Indeed, each map $F \colon F^n_* A \to F^{n+1}_* A$ is a universal homeomorphism, so the same goes for $A \to B$. In particular, $B$ is local and $A \to B$ is local. Moreover, the Frobenius on $B/\mathfrak m_B$ is surjective since the same goes for $B$, and $A/\mathfrak m_A \to B/\mathfrak m_B$ is algebraic since $A \to B$ is integral [Tag [04DF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DF)]. So we conclude that $B/\mathfrak m_B$ is algebraically closed since it is algebraic over a separably closed field as well as perfect. $\square$

On the other hand, if $A$ is *normal* of mixed characteristic $(0,p)$, then this is possible if and only if $A/\mathfrak m_A$ is already algebraically closed. Indeed, a universal homeomorphism $A \to B$ is integral by [Tag [04DF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DF)] and radicial by [Tag [01S4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S4)], so $\operatorname{Frac}(A) \to \operatorname{Frac}(B)$ is purely inseparable (algebraic). Since $\operatorname{char} A = 0$, this forces $\operatorname{Frac}(A) \stackrel\sim\to \operatorname{Frac}(B)$, hence by normality $A \stackrel\sim\to B$. $\square$

The remaining case where $A$ is non-normal of mixed characteristic (for example, it could have characteristic $p^n$ for some $n$) is mysterious to me. Even for $A$ integral of mixed characteristic $(0,p)$, I find it hard to picture how you can fit a local ring $B$ between $A$ and $\operatorname{Frac} A$ whose residue field is the algebraic closure of $A/\mathfrak m_A$. Better ask Brian Conrad or something...

---

¹ Note on notation: $F^n_*A$ is a compromise between writing $A^{1/p^n}$, which is not quite right when $A$ is not a domain, and denoting all of the objects in the colimit by $A$, which is confusing. The notation $F^n_*A$ refers to the affine morphism $F^n \colon \operatorname{Spec} A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$, where we think of an $A$-algebra $B$ as the quasi-coherent sheaf of algebras on $\operatorname{Spec} A$ given by $f_* B$ (or really $f_* \mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec} B}$) for $f \colon \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ induced by $A \to B$.